# CakePHP 3.3.15 multiple matching() chained with OR

Tags: php, cakephp, associations, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

I'm trying to implement a global search mechenism in my **CakePHP 3.3.15** app - this involves searching the Parent table for a value plus searching all the associated tables for the same value. I'm using `matching()`, but I can't find a way to **combine multiple matching() into one query object using OR**.

It looks like matching() will narrow down the result set and calling matching() consecutively will use the object modified by the previous matching() call.

This is what I have:

```
$query = $this->$modelName->find();         
$query->matching('Colonies', function ($q) {
                return $q->where(['OR' => [
                    'Colonies.colony_id' => 10003,
                    'Colonies.project_id' => 6
                ]]);
            });
debug($query->count()); //returns 4 entries

$query->matching('Projects', function ($q) {
                return $q->where(['OR' => [
                    'Projects.id' => 1,
                    'Projects.project_status_id' => 3
                ]]);
            });
debug($query->count()); //returns 1 entry. However, when the previous matching() is removed, it will return 2 entries
```

What else I have tried so far:

1. using `innerJoinWith()` instead of matching() - same result, just the result set is lacking associated fields (exactly as said in the CookBook)
2. using `$this->$modelName->find()->contain('ChildTable', function ($q) { return $q->where(['ChildTable.FieldName' => 'some value']});` - this does not seem to work at all (doesn't filter the result set)
3. Combining the result sets manually to force OR behavior - I'm using pagination later in the code, so I can't work on the result sets directly - I need a single Query object to pass to the paginator.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Matching will apply conditions on `JOIN` level, so each set of `matching()` conditions will apply independently, and since `matching()` creates `INNER` joins, both joins will exclude records.

Check the generated SQL, your multiple `matching()` conditions will create SQL similar to:

```sql
INNER JOIN colonies ON colonies.colony_id = 10003 OR colonies.project_id = 6
INNER JOIN projects ON projects.id = 1 OR projects.project_status_id = 3
```

What you are looking for requires to use A) `LEFT` joins, so that the joins themselves do not excude records, and B) to apply the conditions on the main query, in order to be able to filter the records based on the joined tables:

```
$query = $this->$modelName
    ->find()
    ->leftJoinWith('Colonies')
    ->leftJoinWith('Projects')
    ->where([
        'OR' => [
            'Colonies.colony_id' => 10003,
            'Colonies.project_id' => 6,
            'Projects.id' => 1,
            'Projects.project_status_id' => 3
        ]
    ])
    ->group($modelName . '.id');
```

Due to the nature of joins you may also need to group on the main models primary key in order to avoid dupplicate results.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Using leftJoinWith](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-leftjoinwith)**

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you! I just had to add `->contain()` to  the chain to include associated table values in the result set. btw. This solution crossed my mind at one point, but I didn't think CakePHP would handle lookup tables in the case of many-to-many relationship. Looks like it's smarter than I thought.